# How to write Regular Expression in perl with generic way

Tags: regex, perl

I have written code as:

```
$body =~ s/&Iacute;/Í/g;    
$body =~ s/&Oacute;/Ó/g;    
$body =~ s/&Uacute;/Ú/g;   
$body =~ s/&Yacute;/Ý/g;
```

But this is not a good way.

Could you please provide a generic solution?

Answer (score 7):

This is a solved problem as currently phrased:

```
use HTML::Entities qw(decode_entities);
$unescaped_body = decode_entities($escaped_body);
```

If you really want to do arbitrary pairs of in and out, you should set it up as a hash.

```
my %remap = (
   red   => "rojo",
   white => "blanco",
   blue  => "azul",
);

while (my($from, $to) = each %remap) {
    $text =~ s/\Q$from/$to/g;
}
```

But that will be slow; there are better ways of doing it, but you probably aren't ready for them yet.

Comment: ow, that's a rather awful implementation! 1) Poor performance. 2) Unpredictable recursive replacement (for other map entries). 3) Lack of anchoring ("offwhite" => "offblanco")